# ApiController does not always return data in BadRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I am using an ASP.NET Core 2.2 ApiController and I have the following:

```
[ApiController]
public class PostController : Controller {
  [HttpGet("posts")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Get() {
    return BadRequest();
  }
}
```

In this case I get the following response:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "0HLMFSL0C7SKB:00000001"
}
```

But if I return some data as follows:

```
[ApiController]
public class PostController : Controller {
  [HttpGet("posts")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Get() {
    List<String> errors = new List<String> { "Code is invalid" };
    return BadRequest(new { errors = errors });
  }
}
```

I get the following:

```
{
  "errors": ["Code is invalid"]
}
```

Why does ApiController adds type, title, status and traceId when no content is returned?

I would like the responses to be always similar like:

```
{
  "errors": ["Code is invalid"],
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "0HLMFSL0C7SKB:00000001"
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I am not seeing any of that extra data in my environment. Are you sure you don't have some Middleware or Filter that is adding that extra data?

Answer (score 13):

Instead of returning a `BadRequest()` result you just need to return a `ValidationProblem()` result instead. This will give you the ProblemDetails object response with the current ModelState errors populated.

Comment: Simplest solution ever! Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

The default `ControllerBase.BadRequest()` response content is because you have the `[ApiController]` attribute applied to your controller. This is [documented online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#problem-details-for-error-status-codes):

> When the compatibility version is 2.2 or later, MVC transforms an error result (a result with status code 400 or higher) to a result with `ProblemDetails`. The `ProblemDetails` type is based on the RFC 7807 specification for providing machine-readable error details in an HTTP response.

This includes the `type`, `title`, `status` and `traceId` values.

If you do not have `[ApiController]` applied then `ControllerBase.BadRequest()` will return an empty response with `HTTP 400` status code.

All overloads of `ControllerBase.BadRequest` that accept a `value` or `model` response object will serialize and return that instead of using the `ApiController` default response.

Comment: Just to add to this answer - part of the confusion is that BadRequestResult (which you get when you return BadRequest() implements IClientErrorActionResult, which then goes through the additional plumbing and comes out with a standard error.

However, BadRequestObjectResult, which is what you get when you return BadRequest(something) does not implement this interface, and so sails through unchanged.

Comment: The better solution is returning ValidationProblem, see an answer by Codemunkie. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58683066/245460

Answer (score 6):

For `ProblemDetails`, it depends on whether the `ObjectResult` inherited from `IClientErrorActionResult`.

You could follow steps below for a workaround:

1. `MyBadRequestObjectResult`

   ```
   public class MyBadRequestObjectResult : BadRequestObjectResult, IClientErrorActionResult
   {
       public MyBadRequestObjectResult() : base((object)null)
       {
       }

       public MyBadRequestObjectResult(object error) : base(error)
       {
       }
   }
   ```
2. Custom `ProblemDetailsErrorFactory`

   ```
   public class ProblemDetailsErrorFactory: IClientErrorFactory
   {
       private static readonly string TraceIdentifierKey = "traceId";
       private static readonly string ErrorsKey = "errors";
       private readonly ApiBehaviorOptions _options;

       public ProblemDetailsErrorFactory(IOptions<ApiBehaviorOptions> options)
       {
           _options = options?.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
       }

       public IActionResult GetClientError(ActionContext actionContext, IClientErrorActionResult clientError)
       {
           var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
           {
               Status = clientError.StatusCode,
               Type = "about:blank",
           };

           if (clientError.StatusCode is int statusCode &&
               _options.ClientErrorMapping.TryGetValue(statusCode, out var errorData))
           {
               problemDetails.Title = errorData.Title;
               problemDetails.Type = errorData.Link;
               SetErrors(actionContext, problemDetails);
               SetTraceId(actionContext, problemDetails);
           }

           return new ObjectResult(problemDetails)
           {
               StatusCode = problemDetails.Status,
               ContentTypes =
               {
                   "application/problem+json",
                   "application/problem+xml",
               },
           };
       }
       internal static void SetErrors(ActionContext actionContext, ProblemDetails problemDetails)
       {
           if (actionContext is ResultExecutingContext resultExecutingContext)
           {
               if (resultExecutingContext.Result is BadRequestObjectResult result)
               {
                   problemDetails.Extensions[ErrorsKey] = result.Value;
               }
           }
           //var errors = actionContext.HttpContext.
       }
       internal static void SetTraceId(ActionContext actionContext, ProblemDetails problemDetails)
       {
           var traceId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? actionContext.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
           problemDetails.Extensions[TraceIdentifierKey] = traceId;
       }

   }
   ```
3. Register `ProblemDetailsErrorFactory`

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.TryAddSingleton<IClientErrorFactory, ProblemDetailsErrorFactory>();

       services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
   }
   ```
4. Controller Action

   ```
   [ApiController]
   public class PostController : Controller
   {
       [HttpGet("posts")]
       public IActionResult Get()
       {
           return new MyBadRequestObjectResult();
       }
       [HttpGet("posts1")]
       public IActionResult Get1()
       {
           List<String> errors = new List<String> { "Code is invalid" };
           return new MyBadRequestObjectResult(errors);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I managed to get this working, however, it seems like a lot of hoops to jump through, is there an easier way?

Comment: I am on .Net core 3, implemented what is suggested here. However I am not getting the breakpoint getting hit in GetClientError. Any suggestions?

Comment: The better solution is returning ValidationProblem, see an answer by Codemunkie. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58683066/245460

Answer (score 2):

Its work for me

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SuppressConsumesConstraintForFormFileParameters = true;
    options.SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters = true;
    options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't want to use `ValidationProblem()`.

Just use [ControllerBase.Problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.problem)

Example:

```
public IActionResult Post()
{
    // ...

    return Problem("msg", statusCode: (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

Which outputs

```json
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "msg",
  "traceId": "xxxxx"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to serialize your bad request using JsonConvert.

return BadRequest(JsonConvert.Serialize(new List { “Code is invalid” }));

Comment: This did not work for me, I suspect this is because I am using the ApiController attribute and this information is being lost in conversion as mentioned by Dai